# How to calculate load on roller to create given deflection?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, deflection

I am trying to calculate what loading on a fixed roller will create a predetermined maximum deflection. I ran some calculations, but the values I'm getting are significantly lower than I would expect.

Attached are the calculations.

Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: what is a: "fixed roller supported"? would you please type your question and work you have done.

Comment: "supported" should not have been there, and is fixed now.